# advanced .htaccess mod_rewrite from domain to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I've found a few threads with similar issues, but haven't had any luck modifying the answers to try and meet the requirements of my site. I have a primary domain, and re-write rules in place to redirect www domain to non-www domain, mapped like this:

```
primarydoamin.uk => primarydomain.uk
www.primarydomain.uk => primarydomain.uk

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^primarydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.primarydomain.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.primarydomain.uk$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ primarydomain.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've a number of add-on / mapped domains against my hosting and I'd like to rewrite based upon a pattern:

1. drop 'www'
2. rewrite to a sub-directory of the primary domain (with periods '.' replaced to dashes '-')
3. only execute when the above rule, redirecting www domain to non-www domain traffic is not met, for example:

   ```
   www.fishandchips.co.uk => primarydomain.uk/closed/fishandchips-co-uk
   www.mushypeas.com => primarydomain.uk/closed/mushypeas-com
   pukkapie.uk => primarydomain.uk/closed/pukkapie-uk
   ```

Currently I'm copying and pasting the following logic:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?fishandchips.co.uk$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://primarydomain.uk/closed/fishandchips-co-uk [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You can't internally redirect different domain names so that won't work.

Comment: @Prix have edited the post with correct rule

Comment: @aidanhammond so what is your problem? You haven't told us if your first set of rules are working or not. Then you said you want to redirect additional domains to a sub directory of your main domain is that working and you want a more automated way for it or is it not working? You will have to provide more details on what is not working and what happens so we can help you.

Comment: @Prix Yes, all is working, but I'm looking for advice on how to achieve the steps outlined in the post without manually adding and configuring additional lines in the .htaccess file for each domain added.

Comment: @Prix thanks for your help - it's certainly part working. It rewrites traffic to: http://primarydomain.uk/closed/-/ or http://primarydomain.uk/closed/--/ depending on domain extension, but it's not currently picking up the domain and extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first set of rules can be resumed as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?primarydomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.primarydomain.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://primarydomain.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For your second set of rules I would try something like:

```
# This one will work for domains with single extension like .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !primarydomain.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://primarydomain.uk/closed/%1-%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# This one will work for domains with 2 extensions like .co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !primarydomain.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://primarydomain.uk/closed/%1-%2-%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` at the end will ensure it passes down any URL it was coming from that domain.

NOTE: Keep in mind this is an untested solution. It should work as expected, however it does not take into account multilevel sub domains into it, which you will have to adjust as you go.

Also I have set it to `302` instead of `301`, use `302` until you confirm its fully working then move it to `301` and also make sure you're using a different browser or cleared your cache to make sure you're not viewing a cached redirect.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The solution addresses the problem I was trying to overcome with far less in my .htaccess file. Thanks for your note on %{REQUEST_URI} - Admittedly something I had overlooked.

Comment: You're welcome, there is probably I way to make that shorter but instead I opted to make it simple and readable.